# Find the max real number $\lambda$ s.t. $(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)^2 \ge \lambda \sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n}x_ix_j$ for $\forall x_i,x_j \in R$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Find the max real number $\lambda$ s.t. $(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)^2 \ge \lambda \sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n}x_ix_j$ for $\forall x_i,x_j \in R$.

I think the maximum must be no less than zero, for $\lambda=0$ satisities the condition. I have changed the inequality to:

$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+(2-\lambda)\sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n}x_ix_j \ge 0$.
So I guess the max $\lambda$ is $2$, which I cannot prove.

Is this correct? If so, how to prove this?

Comment: Yes, it's for all $x_i\in R$, not $x_i \ge 0$. Besides, I don't understand your example, for in the condition, it's $(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2$, not $t^2+t^2$.

Comment: This is related to Newton's identities and the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: To prove that the max is 2 (which I'm not confirming if it is), you could show that for $ \lambda > 2$, there is a set of $ x_i$ that do not satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is written as
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\ge \lambda
\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{2}$$
or
$$\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \ge (\lambda - 2) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2.$$

Letting $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n = 1$,
we have $\lambda n \ge (\lambda - 2)n^2$
or $\lambda \le \frac{2n}{n - 1}$.

We claim that the maximum of $\lambda$ is $\frac{2n}{n - 1}$. It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2n}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \ge \left(\frac{2n}{n - 1} - 2\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2$$
or
$$n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \ge
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2$$
which is clearly true.